# Problems parsing some Tweets

Tags: php, html, twitter

I have created a function to parse some data from twitter URLs and that way embed the tuit. This URLs are taken from a textarea filled by a user, because it usage is for a forum. I allow users to introduce a Twitter URL between [twitter] and [/twitter] tags, and once sent, the text is process with PHP and the URLs extracted. Here is where the following code runs:

```
$titulo = "";
$fecha = "";
$nombrecompleto = "";
$nombre_usuario = "";


$url = "https://twitter.com/XboxQwik/status/884071790481256448";

$html = file_get_html($url);

$posts = $html->find('div[class=js-tweet-text-container]');
$titulo = $posts[0]->find('p',0);

$posts = $html->find('div[class=client-and-actions]');
$fecha = $posts[0]->find('span',0);

$posts = $html->find('span[class=FullNameGroup]');
$nombrecompleto = $posts[0]->find('strong',0);

$posts = $html->find('a[class=js-user-profile-link]');
$nombre_usuario = $posts[0]->find('span',1);


$codigo = generateRandomString();

//traducimos la imagen a código html
  $url_html = "<blockquote class=\"twitter-tweet\" data-lang=\"es\"><p lang=\"es\" dir=\"ltr\">" . $titulo . "</p>&mdash; " . $nombrecompleto . " (" . $nombre_usuario . ") <a href=" . $url . ">" . $fecha . "</a></blockquote>";
```

I have been trying it with many tuits and work fine, but with this user I´m enable to parse any of its tuits.

https://twitter.com/XboxQwik

Don't know why.

Comment: Why don't you just use the API instead of violating the Twitter TOS? https://twitter.com/en/tos "scraping the Services without the prior consent of Twitter is expressly prohibited"

Comment: The usage will be in a forum, so the users giving the URL from Twitter I wanted to parse just the needed data to embed the tweet, just that. I didn't know that it is prohibited. @ceejayoz